# вызов нетранзакционного метода из транзакционных в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть два  `@Transactional` метода,оба из разных мест,но вызывают один и тот же метод,который ****не** `@Transactional`** и этот метод служит для выборки данных из бд(обычный select).Что произойдет,если два transactional метода одновременно вызовут метод для выборки,хочется знать какие могут быть последствия и есть ли связь с `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`(Row was updated or deleted by another transaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аннотация `@Transactional` "накручивает" прокси (Dynamic Proxy) и выделяется в отдельный контекст. Таким образом, если 2 метода, помеченных аннотацией `@Transactional` вызовут метод без такой аннотации, будут созданы 2 отдельных контекста без взаимного влияния друг на друга. И результат их работы будет разным.

Контекст транзакции прокидывается по всему стеку вызовов, то есть распространяется и на методы, не помеченные аннотацией `@Transactional`, находящихся ниже в стеке вызовов.

По поводу `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` связь есть и вам нужно понимать принципы работы реляционных баз данных и требования ACID.

Comment: а вы говорите что связь есть,но судя по вышеизложенному,проблемы с одновременным доступом не будет,т.e.каждый поток будет видеть новые изменения

Comment: @Алексей имеется ввиду, что при неумелой работе с хибером, можно ловить ошибки подобного рода)